# symfony doctrine query result and execute function

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have this doctrine query in symfony. It returns a lot of rows when i run mysql code generated by this dql query in phpBB but when i run it in symfony and access its results with this code:

```
foreach ($this->courses as $course){
 echo "<br>".$course->firstname;}
```

it returns only one name. Also when i try to get **$course->title**, this error appears
**Unknown record property / related component "title" on "Students"**

Query:

```
$q= Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('s.firstname,
                  s.middlename,
                  s.lastname,
                  p.program,
                  c.title,
                  pc.year')
         ->from('Students s')
         ->leftJoin('s.Programs p')
         ->leftJoin('p.Programcourses pc')
         ->leftJoin('pc.Courses c')
         ->where("idstudents = ?",2);
$this->courses=$q->execute();
```

schema.yml:

```
    Courses:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: courses
  columns:
    idcourses:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    title:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Programcourses:
      local: idcourses
      foreign: idcourses
      type: many
Programcourses:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: programcourses
  columns:
    idprogramcourses:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    idprograms:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    idcourses:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    year:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Courses:
      local: idcourses
      foreign: idcourses
      type: one
    Programs:
      local: idprograms
      foreign: idprograms
      type: one
Programs:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: programs
  columns:
    idprograms:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    program:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Programcourses:
      local: idprograms
      foreign: idprograms
      type: many
    Students:
      local: idprograms
      foreign: idprograms
      type: many
Roles:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: roles
  columns:
    idroles:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    role:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
Students:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: students
  columns:
    idstudents:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    firstname:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    middlename:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    lastname:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    idprograms:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    session:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    username:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Programs:
      local: idprograms
      foreign: idprograms
      type: one
Teachers:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: teachers
  columns:
    idteachers:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    firstname:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    lastname:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    username:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how i get it work...

```
$q= Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('s.firstname,
              s.middlename,
              s.lastname,
              p.program,
              c.title,
              pc.year')
     ->from('Students s')
     ->leftJoin('s.Programs p')
     ->leftJoin('p.Programcourses pc')
     ->leftJoin('pc.Courses c')
     ->where("idstudents = ".$studentid);

//$this->query=$q->getSqlQuery();
$q->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
$this->Student=$q->execute(array());
```

and in template

```
<?php foreach ($Student as $student): ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $student['c_title'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $student['pc_year'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $student['p_program'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your top node is the a `Students` object, because you use `Students` in the `from()`

Your error describe this

> Also when i try to get `$course->title`, this error appears `Unknown record property / related component "title" on "Students"`

because you have a `Students` object, not a `Courses` one (where `title` belongs)

You are confusing yourself using

> $this->courses=$q->execute();

---

```
$q= Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select('s.firstname,
          s.middlename,
          s.lastname,
          p.program,
          c.title,
          pc.year')
 ->from('Students s')
 ->leftJoin('s.Programs p')
 ->leftJoin('p.Programcourses pc') 
 ->leftJoin('pc.Courses c')
 ->where("idstudents = ?", $studentid); // beware to SQL injection, use parameters

$this->Student=$q->fectchOne(); // as you are only retrieve one in your where clause
$this->Student=$q->execute()->getFirst(); // same
```

---

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $i; /* not sure what this is for */ ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $Student->Programs->Programcourses->Courses->title ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $Student->Programs->Programcourses->year ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $Student->Programs->program ?></td>
</tr>
```

---

If you want `Courses` to be the top, just go for something like:

```
$q= Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select('s.firstname,
          s.middlename,
          s.lastname,
          p.program,
          c.title,
          pc.year')
 ->from('Courses c')
 ->leftJoin('c.Programcourses pc') 
 ->leftJoin('pc.Programs p')
 ->leftJoin('p.Students s')
 ->where("s.idstudents = ?", $studentid);
```

Comment: I tried this solution, the error is almost same **Unknown record property / related component "title" on "Programcourses"**, Moreover this query does not return one record, it returns many records.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Instead of $course->firstname and $course->title, you want $course->getFirstName() and $course->getTitle().
- You should use singular names for your tables instead of plural, e.g. Course instead of Courses.
- The convention in symfony is to use "id" for the primary key name instead of what you're doing.

Fix those problems - especially the first one - and your overall problem should go away.

Comment: Actually, there should be no difference between the two. In fact, the `getXXX` methods aren't part of Doctrine, they're added by Symfony to add an interface that matches Propel. Personally, I'm of the opinion that, whenever possible, only array style notation should be used in templates so they're agnostic as to whether they receive Records or arrays.

Comment: I have tried your answer. $course->getFirstName results this 'adsfasdfsdf'. it is supposed to answer my name. Also when i try to run foreach loop this error occurs. **Unknown record property / related component "getFirstName" on "Students"**

Answer (score 0):

Prepare query like this:

```
public function getAttendanceRecord($employeeId, $date) {
try {
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from("attendanceRecord")
            ->where("employeeId = ?", $employeeId);
    $records = $query->execute();
    if (is_null($records[0]->getId())) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $records;
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    throw new DaoException($ex->getMessage());
}
```

}

And try to get/print like this:

> $attendanceOfTheDay = AttendanceDao::getAttendanceRecord($parameters['employeeId'], $parameters['date'])->toArray();
>   echo '  '; print_r($punchInTImeOfTheDay);
>   exit();