# Using a variable from a form in a query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to query the department name from one table, using the id submitted from a form submission to another table by matching the id from the form submission to the id in the Department table.

```
$deptQuery =  $form->getValue('department_id');

      $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('d.name')
        ->from('Department d')
        ->where('id = ?', $deptQuery)
        ->execute();
      ;
echo $q;
```

This is my output:

```
<pre>
Doctrine_Collection
data : Array(
   0 : Object(Department)
)
</pre>
```

I can get the department_id variable to display like this:

```
$deptQuery =  $form->getValue('department_id');
echo $deptquery;
```

It will show the correct id:

```
 5 (for example)
```

How can I write the query so it takes the submitted form department_id and matches it to the id in the Department table and outputs the department name?

ie rather than 5, it outputs the photography dept.

This has been addressed and resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789389/symfony-doctrine-query-result-and-execute-function). Sorry for my amateur posting.

I just needed to cut the array to one return and pull the first.

```
$dept = $q->fetchOne();
$dept = $q->execute()->getFirst();
```

Comment: I don't know symfony but this sounds like a join to me.

Comment: So lets say I throw in a left join like this: ->leftJoin('d.Users u'), I am still getting the same result. Does the variable ($deptQuery) belong somewhere in the leftJoin tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method call [find()](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine#chapter_08_sub_retrieving_records_by_primary_key) which does exactly what you want ... use it like this :

```
$dept = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Department')->find($id);
```

The `$id` parameter must be a primary key - which in your case it is (im assuming). This will return a `Department` object matching your primary key - to get the name you can just use `$dept->getName()`